# How do I remove elements not matching conditions with MongoDB $pull?

Tags: arrays, node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-update

I have a MongDB document that looks like this:

```
{
   values: [{val:true}, {val:false}, {val:true}, {val:"dgfdshfsj"}]
}
```

How would I use the MongoDB $pull operator to remove all elements from the array which are not `true`, somewhat like this:

```
db.myCollection.update({}, {$pull{values:{val:!true}}}, {multi:true})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)** operator in your query together with the logical operator **[`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/#op._S_ne)** as follows:

```
db.myCollection.updateMany(
    { "values": { "$elemMatch": { "val": { "$ne": true } } } },
    { "$pull": { "values": { "val": { "$ne": true } } } }
)
```